# How to compile PrimePoolMiner on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm trying to compile a crypto currency miner on my original Pi B+, but I keep having issues.

This is what I'm compiling.
https://github.com/Nexusoft/PrimePoolMiner

Here's my error:

```
g++ -c -pthread -m64 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wall -             Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-    unused-parameter -Wformat -Wformat-security -g -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -I/home/pi/PrimePoolMiner -   I/home/pi/PrimePoolMiner/build -I/home/pi/PrimePoolMiner/hash -O2 -MMD -o build/skein.o hash/skein.cpp
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m64’
makefile:58: recipe for target 'build/skein.o' failed
make: *** [build/skein.o] Error 1
```

Here's the error after I remove `-m64`

```
pi@raspi:~/PrimePoolMiner $ make
g++ -c -pthread -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-unused-parameter -Wformat     -Wformat-security -g -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -I/home/pi/PrimePoolMiner -I/home/pi/PrimePoolMiner/build -I/home/pi/    PrimePoolMiner/hash -O2 -MMD -o build/util.o util.cpp
In file included from util.cpp:1:0:
util.h:4:53: fatal error: boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
                                                     ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:44: recipe for target 'build/util.o' failed
make: *** [build/util.o] Error 1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing Boost libraries, so the next step would be to install those:

```
apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

PS. You may want to take a look in [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?&t=8111) if you have further issues. The relationship between compatible Boost version, GCC version and supported C++ features is far from trivial.