# C++ problem: boost/asio.hpp non existing

Tags: pi-3b+, c++

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3B+. I'm trying to compile a rather massive C++ package given to me from somewhere else. However `make` fails compiling. It cannot find `boost/asio.hpp`. I simplified the problem into this minimal version. This is my `helloboost.c`

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main() {
  printf("hello boost\n");
  return(0);
}
```

If I comment out the `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` line it compiles with `g++ helloboost.c` just fine and works, but with this version the following error appears:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/tmp_tests $ g++ helloboost.c 
helloboost.c:5:26: fatal error: boost/asio.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/asio.hpp>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

Apparently it does find the other include files. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33222609/11199684) is a similar question but it has not been answered. A comment there suggests making it a "SSCCE", I don't know what that means. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to install the boost headers.

Comment: @RalfFriedl how do I install them? `sudo apt-get install boost` does not work.

Comment: It depends on the distribution, they should be named something like `boost-devel` or `libboost-dev`.

Comment: @RalfFriedl that's right, I installed `libboost-dev` and it worked, thank you! Please make this into an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get Bluetooth/Bluetooth.h for Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/where-to-get-bluetooth-bluetooth-h-for-raspberry-pi)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev am not sure if it does. I don't have the RPi any more and don't quite remember what was my particular purpose back then, but "boost" was one of the early approaches. In my final result I did not use boost at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the headers for the boost libraries.

For most libraries, there are the runtime packages and the development packages. The runtime packages are needed to execute the programs and for development, the development packages are needed only for development. Usually the development packages have a `-devel` or `-dev` suffix.

For the boost library, install `libboost-dev`.

Comment: Further on this, later I hit another bug: I was missing `boost_thread`, `boost_chrono` etc. The solution was to install `libboost-all-dev` as in this: [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/60349/103870]

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that I have used is to install the standalone non-`boost` version via

```
apt-get install libasio-dev
```

The last I checked there was still a somewhat inadvertent dependency on one of the boost libraries anyway, but perhaps that has been resolved by now or it may be that the portions of `asio` that you need are unaffected.  I found this to be a useful approach since many of the features of `boost` have already found their way into the C++ standard and into `gcc`.